# How to deal with timestamps without a timezone?

Tags: google-bigquery

The NYC bike and taxi datasets list the time when events happened in local time. Timestamps like `2018-01-07 10:30:00` means it was 10am in NY at the time.

When I ingest these timestamps into BigQuery, BigQuery assumes they are GMT - appending the incorrect timezone information.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

2 choices:

- Use `DATETIME` instead of `TIMESTAMP` - `DATETIME` has the same information than `TIMESTAMP`, except no timezone information is added.
- Since this is NY, you can append the `US/Eastern` timezone when ingesting - it will correctly identify summer daylight saving changes and so on

For example:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP('2018-3-10 10:00:00', 'US/Eastern')
     , TIMESTAMP('2018-5-10 10:00:00', 'US/Eastern')
2018-03-10 15:00:00 UTC 
2018-05-10 14:00:00 UTC
```